# Incorrect checksum for free freed object - 2D double array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc

I'm getting the error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x100502048: incorrect checksum for freed      
object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

The thing is, this error happens randomly. Sometimes it the program executes and I get the answer I am looking for, and sometimes this error pops up.

I am using xcode to debug, and it points to this function definition:

```
double **Hermite_coeff(double *z, double *output, double *deriv, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    double **H;

    H = calloc(2*n, sizeof(double*)); // <-----Error points to here

    for (i = 0; i < 2*n; ++i)
        H[i] = calloc((i+1),sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        H[2*i][0] = output[i];
        H[2*i+1][0] = output[i];
        H[2*i+1][1] = deriv[i];

        if (i != 0)
        {
            H[2*i][1] = (H[2*i][0] - H[2*i-1][0])/(z[2*i] - z[2*i-1]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 2; i < 2*n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 2; j <= i; j++)
        {
            H[i][j] = (H[i][j-1] - H[i-1][j-1])/(z[i] - z[i-j]);
        }
    }

    return H;
}
```

This is the function that generates the double *z.

```
double *Hermite_z_sequence(double *input, int n)
{
    int i;
    double *z;

    if ((z = calloc(2*n, sizeof(double))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Malloc failed in Hermite_z_sequence\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 2*n; ++i)
    {
        z[2*i] = input[i];
        z[2*i+1] = input[i];
    }

    return z;
}
```

This is ultimately what I am trying to run.

```
double Hermite_interpolation(double *z, double **coeff, int n, double x)
{
    int i, j;
    double result, sum;

    result = coeff[0][0];

    for (i = 1; i < 2*n; i++)
    {
        sum = 1;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            sum *= (x - z[j-1]);

        result += (coeff[i][i]*sum);
    }

    return result;

}
```

This is how I define my input, output, and deriv:

```
// Input
double input[] = {0.30, 0.32, 0.35};

// Output
double sin_x[] = {0.29552, 0.31457, 0.34290};

// Derivative of sin_x
double cos_x[] = {0.95534, 0.94924, 0.93937};
```

My main():

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // initializing the given parameters for the assignment
    int n;
    double actual_output, x, *z, **h_coeff, hermite_result;

    double input[] = {0.30, 0.32, 0.35};
    double sin_x[] = {0.29552, 0.31457, 0.34290};
    double cos_x[] = {0.95534, 0.94924, 0.93937};

    n = 3;
    x = 0.34;

    z = Hermite_z_sequence(input, n);

    h_coeff = Hermite_coeff(z, sin_x, cos_x, n);

    hermite_result = Hermite_interpolation(z, h_coeff, n, x);

    actual_output = sin(x);

    printf("Hermite H_5(%.2f) = %.7f\n", x, hermite_result);
    printf("Relative error: %.7f\n\n", relative_error(actual_output, hermite_result));

    h_coeff = destroy_diagonal_2D_array(h_coeff, 2*n);

    free(z);

    return 0;
}
```

And sometimes this shows:

```
Hermite H_5(0.34) = 0.3334889
Relative error: 0.0000054
```

And at other times this shows:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1004090e8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(lldb)
```

Comment: "*The thing is, this error happens randomly*" -> Undefined Behavior. The solution is, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and find the actual problem.

Comment: Not familiar with the algorithm: are you sure this is correct? `calloc((i+1),sizeof(double));` – it allocates increasingly more memory per sub-element, but you appear to use only `[0]` and `[1]` (where `[0]` has only enough space for **1** double).

Comment: @usr2564301 Probably correct, google *Hermite polynomials*. I don't remember their formulas and building expressions, but perhaps there are more elements per polynomial as the order of it increases with *n* for the *n*-th polynomial. I know them from Quantum Mechanics, because they represent the solution to the Harmonic Oscilator problem in the coordinates vector space. That should help you find info about them.

Comment: Have a look at this, and tell me if it looks right to you: 

`for (i = 0; i < 2*n; ++i) {z[2*i] = input[i]; z[2*i+1] = input[i]; }`

Assuming we have `z = calloc(2*n, sizeof(double))`. In that loop, you step far over `2*n`. In the condition for `for`, you probably meant to write `i < n` instead of `i < 2*n`.

Comment: @user934063 This fixed my problem. I was only supposed to be accessing up to 2n-1, but z[2*i+1] was bringing me to 4n-1, thanks.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Forgive my ignorance of valgrind, I will look up what that is. And yes, the coefficients for a Hermite polynomial are along the diagonal of the left diagonal matrix generated with this algorithm.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Malloc failed in Hermite_z_sequence\n");` 1)  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when handling an error indication from a system function, call `perror()` so both the enclosed text and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding: `z[2*i] = input[i];` and `z[2*i+1] = input[i];`  the size of the array `z[]` is 2n  and the value of `i` is 0...<2n  So 2i will be 4n  That is beyond the end of the allocated array.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `doubledouble Hermite_interpolation(
                        double *z,
                        double **coeff,
                        int n, double x) cos_x[] = {0.95534, 0.94924, 0.93937};`  there is the needed separator just before the variable name: `cos_x[]`

Comment: regarding: `double *Hermite_z_sequence(double *input, int n)`  This statement is missing the trailing semicolon ':'

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix the warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )   The compiling the posted code results in dozens of warning messages.  Fix them, the post an EDIT of the code

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `initField()` fails to set the `.next` fields so those fields could be anything.  Because of that, there is some undefined behavior in the rest of the program, like: in the function: `updateField()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this, and tell me if it looks right to you:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2*n; ++i) 
{
    z[2*i] = input[i]; 
    z[2*i+1] = input[i]; 
}
```

Assuming we have

```
z = calloc(2*n, sizeof(double))
```

In that loop, you step far over `2*n`. In the condition for `for`, you probably meant to write `i < n` instead of `i < 2*n`